# Construction of a .dll file and the intermediate .lib

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dynamic, static-libraries, import-libraries

Below is an excerpt from [link1.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d.aspx)

> Microsoft introduced __export in the 16-bit compiler version of Visual
>   C++ to allow the compiler to generate the export names automatically
>   and place them in a .lib file. This .lib file can then be used just
>   like a static .lib to link with a DLL. In newer compiler versions, you
>   can export data, functions, classes, or class member functions from a
>   DLL using the __declspec(dllexport) keyword. __declspec(dllexport)
>   adds the export directive to the object file so you do not need to use
>   a .def file.

I understand the above paragraph to an extent but not very well.

Below is an excerpt from [link2.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/d91k01sh.aspx)

> When building the DLL, the linker uses the .def file to create an
>   export (.exp) file and an import library (.lib) file. The linker then
>   uses the export file to build the DLL file. Executables that
>   implicitly link to the DLL link to the import library when they are
>   built.

Now, this makes me confused and made me ask the below questions:

1. Could anybody, in simple words, tell me what the term **exporting**
   really means? I believe this is making an object accessible from one
   piece of the code to other - but hey !!
2. When building projects with old libraries, I see .def file in majority
   of them. But the latest compilers automatically exports objects. Would
   the presence of the .def file cause any conflict when converting a older
   version visual studio project to the newer one?
3. What is the use of the .lib(the so called import file) after the generation
   of the .dll. Can it be safely deleted?
4. ARRGGGH !! What is the difference between a static library(.lib) and import library(.lib)? Blunder, huh? But still !!
5. Is the windows specific phenomenon? I believe it is not. What is the Linux counterpart of the so called import file?

Please feel free to rephrase the question if it is not already lucid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> tell me what the term exporting really means?

It simply means telling the linker that it needs to put an entry into the DLL's export table.  The operating system loader uses it later to glue code in different modules together at runtime.

> I see .def file in majority of them

Could be *very* old projects.  Or it was just never started as a project that was meant to create a separate module.  Like a static library so the source code doesn't have the `__declspec` attributes.  Cross-platform libraries are pretty likely to fit that bill.  The C and C++ language specifications still don't have a way to create modules in a standardized way.  Everybody does it, nobody does it the same way.  Massive time drain.

> What is the use of the .lib(the so called import file)

It is necessary in the project that *uses* the DLL.  The linker needs to know that the identifier lives in another building and can't be resolved at link time.  It puts an entry in another table that the operating system loader uses, the import table.  It is a *very* simple file, it just list the names of the exported identifiers.  Theoretically the DLL itself could be used by the linker to figure this out.  Practically that doesn't work because the exported name doesn't have to match the actual name.

> What is the difference between a static library(.lib) and import library(.lib)

A static library contains code that is linked into the project that uses the library.  An import library does not contain code, just a hint that the code is available elsewhere.

> Is the windows specific phenomenon?

Roughly, yes.  The Unixes have the same concept but implement it very differently.

Comment: Thankyou and cheers !! But yet another question, is the export table something that resides in the runtime stack?

Comment: No, it is part of the header of the DLL file.  A place where the loader can easily find it.  Use Dumpbin.exe /exports on any DLL to see what it contains.

Comment: Sounds great ! Regarding `Practically that doesn't work because the exported name doesn't have to match the actual name.` - Is this because of the mangling that is applied to identifiers?

Comment: Yes, that's one very good reason to rename the export.  Or exporting by number instead of name, a (very slight) optimization.

Comment: Understood !! Also, is the import library needed after the after the .dll is created?

Comment: Well, not before.  You don't have to leave it up the loader to glue the code together, you can also do it by hand.  LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress.  Pretty painful but certainly necessary when you try to use the DLL from a different language that doesn't use a linker.